# How to send a Tweet 30 minutes after first received GET- request?

Tags: php, twitter, get, raspberry-pi

I would like to send a Tweet 30 minutes after I receive the 'open' GET-request. My Raspberry Pi sends an 'open' request when the fridge's door is opened and 'close' when the door is closed. The time frame should prevent people forgetting the fridge's door open. How can I do this in PHP?

```
<?php
require_once 'src/twitter.class.php';
$devicename = $_GET["devicename"];
$action     = $_GET["action"];

// If device name and action is not empty
if (!empty($devicename) && !empty($action)) {

    // Create database connection    
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    // Get all info related to received device name
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE devicename='$devicename'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    // If result is useful
    if ($result) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $consumerkey       = $row["consumerkey"];
        $consumersecret    = $row["consumersecret"];
        $accesstoken       = $row["accesstoken"];
        $accesstokensecret = $row["accesstokensecret"];
        $message           = null;

        // If GET parameter has value 'open'
        if ($action == 'opened') {
            // Get related message from database info and send tweet with related tokens
            $message = $row["message1"];
            send_tweet($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret, $message);
        } else if ($action == 'closed') {
            $message = $row["message2"];
            send_tweet($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret, $message);
        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Error at sending tweet! Check your GET parameters!'); </script>";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}

function send_tweet($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret, $message) {
    $twitter  = new Twitter($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

    // Get local time and date
    $datetime = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    try {

        // Send tweet with local time and date and message
        $tweet = $twitter->send($datetime . ' ' . $message);
    }
    catch (TwitterException $e) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error:' . $e->getMessage() . '"); </script>';
        //echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: either have PHP do a `sleep(30*60)` so the script "hangs" until it's time to send the message, or use a system scheduler, e.g. `at`, to schedule your sending job.

Comment: But will the php script still handle the 'closed' request during the sleep? Because it may happen that the user closes the door during the sleep right??

Comment: no. any particular invocation of php will handle only ONE http request. the close request would be entirely separate and handled by another instance of your scsript.

Comment: So how can I implement a way to do both?

Comment: use the scheduled job option. `open` schedules the job. if you receive a `close`, then you just cancel the job.

Comment: Could you please send me an example because I have tried so many things already?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking this as one single process, you can think it as two processess.

On process just detects the open/close events.

Other process tweets if ther is an open event without a close event that has more than 30 minutes

The first process you just insert into database the date and the event and is executed by a GET request.

The second process detects if it's necesary to send a tweet and it can be executed via a cronjob every 5 minutes or every minute. This process just checks if in the database is there an open event without a close event and if this open event has been created 30 or more minutes ago. Just check if the last event for each device is an open event and you can a column called for example tweeted to set this event has been tweeted.

```
Table event:

id: INT autoincrement
event: ENUM(open, closed)
date_created: DATETIME
tweeted: INT

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE device = $device ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1;'
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['event'] == 'open' && 
        $row['tweeted'] == 0 &&
        $row['date_created'] < date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-30 minutes"))){
        // Send tweet
        // Update row with tweeted = 1 to not tweet it twice
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show my where in my code I need to add these functions, because it is still not clear to me? I've created the event table.